# Android Button which makes HTTP GET request to a webserver

Tags: android, http, button, webclient

I have found 1 similar thread but it's far from full code and 8 years old. I hope there are some easy to use libraries for web by now but I can hardly find anything next to:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client

My app needs to have 2 buttons. Depending on which button is pushed it will send an authenticated HTTP or HTTPS GET request to a webserver.

Anyone know a good library or even better a complete example source code for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/9749761) and the other answers for that question. Personally I'd suggest *OkHttp* and *retrofit*, which are both mentioned in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp, Valley, Retrofit - pick up any of this - they all are quite simple and easy to start. They are in order from simplest to complex.